# Google Sheets Split row in multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I'm doing a spreadsheet for an event and I need to split a row into multiple rows. It's getting data from a form.

I need a script that can arrange the data like in the blue rectangle.

[image]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @user0 
sure:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JMIBO5QRkN6L9MFry8wWIsEang9PquJX-yxWj7FJ7Wg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
={Sheet1!A1:D1; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN({
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!B2:B); "♣"&Sheet1!B2:B&"♣"&Sheet1!C2:C&"♣"&Sheet1!D2:D;)\
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!E2:E); "♣"&Sheet1!E2:E&"♣"&Sheet1!F2:F&"♣"&Sheet1!G2:G;)\
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!H2:H); "♣"&Sheet1!H2:H&"♣"&Sheet1!I2:I&"♣"&Sheet1!J2:J;)}); "♦"&Sheet1!A2:A&{
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!B2:B); "♣"&Sheet1!B2:B&"♣"&Sheet1!C2:C&"♣"&Sheet1!D2:D;)\
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!E2:E); "♣"&Sheet1!E2:E&"♣"&Sheet1!F2:F&"♣"&Sheet1!G2:G;)\
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!H2:H); "♣"&Sheet1!H2:H&"♣"&Sheet1!I2:I&"♣"&Sheet1!J2:J;)};))
 ;;999^99));;999^99)); "♦")); "♣")))}
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X7NuM-AADO7YYAvr10rmcpEJ_k3nx1hKoBLnU2WJRWc/edit#gid=1419074068&range=L1)

---

```
={Sheet1!A1:H1; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN({
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!F2:F); "♣"&Sheet1!F2:F&"♣"&Sheet1!G2:G&"♣"&Sheet1!H2:H;)\
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!I2:I); "♣"&Sheet1!I2:I&"♣"&Sheet1!J2:J&"♣"&Sheet1!K2:K;)\
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!L2:L); "♣"&Sheet1!L2:L&"♣"&Sheet1!M2:M&"♣"&Sheet1!N2:N;)}); 
 "♦"&Sheet1!A2:A&"♣"&Sheet1!B2:B&"♣"&Sheet1!C2:C&"♣"&Sheet1!D2:D&"♣"&Sheet1!E2:E&{
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!F2:F); "♣"&Sheet1!F2:F&"♣"&Sheet1!G2:G&"♣"&Sheet1!H2:H;)\
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!I2:I); "♣"&Sheet1!I2:I&"♣"&Sheet1!J2:J&"♣"&Sheet1!K2:K;)\
 IF(LEN(Sheet1!L2:L); "♣"&Sheet1!L2:L&"♣"&Sheet1!M2:M&"♣"&Sheet1!N2:N;)};))
 ;;999^99));;999^99)); "♦")); "♣")))}
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X7NuM-AADO7YYAvr10rmcpEJ_k3nx1hKoBLnU2WJRWc/edit#gid=1641630301&range=P1)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I talked with my collegue and he told me that we need more info from the person to show like phone number, email, age, etc, not just the name ( my bad sorry). How I can add more collums to the formula?

Comment: @ComunicaçãoAndreia answer and demo sheet updated. check it out

Comment: Thank You so much, now i understand the formula and tweak if it needs more columns. :)

Answer (score 1):

This **simple** Query formula is your solution.

```
=query({resp3columns!A:D;resp3columns!A2:A,resp3columns!E2:G;resp3columns!A2:A,resp3columns!H2:J},"select * where NOT Col2='' order by Col1",1)
```

[image: split-fold-row2rows]

In the screenshot you can see variations with different numbers of data columns (3, 4, 6)

**ADDED BONUS**
You get your data ordered as well by `Name` or `Model` or any other column you may want.

Here is a [**Demo Spreadsheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MbaoiLzwbulWmydr-SLno9DYb00Hxw_sgoyPnpR4rGE/edit#gid=1091288436&range=A2) you can play with and try out yourself.