# Divide 1 row of data into multiple rows - Registration Data

Tags: google-sheets-query

I have a Google Form for registering multiple children. There is only one mom, but she can have anywhere from 1-3 children she is signing up for daycare. The form give me a sheet with a row with all of this information, but I would like to have a line per child.

I've searched and searched but just can't figure this out.

Once I figure this one out, there will be additional information I will want to pull, such as all of the children per mom (there are additional fields for children the mother has, but are not needing childcare.

Here is a copy of the sheet.  Note the data is fake right now and can be changed.
I updated so this is a public link.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tW5zSxprTig7AhEEU07oqy6GScCEheXykoJrzCx-iI8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome. You need to change your sheet settings to public. In the mean time please also have a look at [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/131593/) as well as the related ones and see if those help. If not let us know.

Comment: Thank you!  Here it is.  I also added some fake data - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tW5zSxprTig7AhEEU07oqy6GScCEheXykoJrzCx-iI8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Looking at your sheet. Are these the JUST the original answer fields from the FormResponses or **have you already added some extra columns?**

Comment: These should be the original fields.  Here is the form.  One exception is I renamed the name fields so they were unique.  I will need to update the form to match once I figure this all out (I wasn't sure if I could have 5 first name fields for example.

Comment: Here is a copy of the form - https://forms.gle/JRM5imBRDoMgQVPy6

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will into it and come back to you. Give me some time please :)

Comment: Thank you SOO very much.  Here is a prefilled in form link as well if you need it.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/12NSm0JfV_A_GV4HcsJRJ1DXrQlVohzDE10ip6YA0MUs/prefill

Comment: The prefilled link cannot be viewed by me. Just prefill 3-5 similar answers and append them to your test sheet and let me know. That should be enough for me. Talk to you soon.

Comment: This seems to be very close, but off somehow.  I changed the tab name to form responses to match this formula I found online -  =query({responses!A:J;responses!A2:D,responses!K2:P;responses!A2:D,responses!Q2:V;responses!A2:D,responses!W2:AB;responses!A2:D,responses!AC2:AH},"select * where Not Col5='' order by Col1")

Comment: The formula you found is my formula on the sheet of the [mentioned answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/131574/). I will tweak it to suit your needs. You can give a try as well.

Comment: Thank you,  I did realize I added a column Amount Received.

Comment: I will send a new sheet shortly with a few answers.

Comment: Sheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rb2mPfAzYZuNbx1H10tp8FwZzrmQgpYorn7bIjUupjU/edit?usp=sharing

Form - 
https://forms.gle/VFBgK6h1YHLfuR1b8

I added columns BCD that will not have any data>

Comment: Also I have some field names that repeat.  Same questions asked for each child name, dob etc.  Do they all need to be unique for this?  I don't want thayt much text on my form if I don't need it.

Comment: Please check your email. I've sent you a request.

Comment: Sorry I have done that now, thank you so much